# Is there a way to maintain ordering with Scala's breakOut?

Tags: scala

I recently discovered breakOut and love how elegant it is, but noticed that it doesn't maintain order.

eg (from REPL):

```
scala> val list = List("apples", "bananas", "oranges")
list: List[String] = List(apples, bananas, oranges)

scala> val hs: HashMap[String, Int] = list.map{x => (x -> x.length)}(breakOut)
hs: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map(bananas -> 7, oranges -> 7, apples -> 6)
```

I like using breakOut since it's really clean and neat but ordering does matter to me. Is there a way to get it to maintain order or do I have to add elements to my hashmap one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see this behavior, because of the fact that `HashMap` is a data structure with undefined order. Even if you see some ordering of the elements in the hash map and it's consistent across the runs, you shouldn't depend on it. If you really need the order, consider using [LinkedHashMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashMap.html)